# huggingface/transformers: cache directory

Tags: caching, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I'm trying to use huggingface transformers.
(Win 11, Python 3.9, jupyternotebook, virtual environment)

When I ran code:

```
from transformers import pipeline
print(pipeline('sentiment-analysis')('I hate you'))
```

I got an error :

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\Users\user/.cache\huggingface'

There's no directory named '.cache' in my user folder,
so I used cache_dir="./cache"
but I want to change the path of the directory permanently.

P.S.

```
import os
os.environ['TRANSFORMERS_CACHE'] = './cache'
```

also didn't work.

Comment: I am not using Windows, but can you set `os.environ['TRANSFORMERS_CACHE'] = './cache'` to an actual windows path and tell me what happens? Keep in mind that you need to set this environment variable before you import transformers!

Comment: "you need to set this environment variable before you import transformers" << This was the key to solving this problem. Thank you

Comment: I am facing the same issue, trying to run the model in a dockerized environment.
My error says: There was a problem when trying to write in your cache folder (./cache). You should set the environment variable TRANSFORMERS_CACHE to a writable directory